# TCP Server multiple packet sending issue

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp, tcpserver

I have written the server client program using linux tcp sockets.

Client ask server for present directory files list by
sending the **ls** command

```
server replies all the list of files in server dir.
I was testing it for more files in server working dir.

server response format in the buffer
file/dir [tab] file_name [tab] file_change_time
for each 1000 files to client.
```

Server Sending Code:

```
#define BUFSIZE 1400

void lsfun(node_t *pclient)
{
    DIR *directory;
    int status;
    int cpylen = 0;
    int msglen = 0;
    unsigned int tt_count = 0;
    unsigned int no_files = 0;
    unsigned int no_sends = 0;
    int clientfd = *(pclient->client_socket);
    char *filectime;
    char *buffer = malloc(BUFSIZE * sizeof(char));
    char *tmp = malloc(BUFSIZE * sizeof(char));
    char ending[] = "#####";
    struct dirent *dir;
    struct stat type;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    chdir(pclient->pwd);
    directory = opendir(".");
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);

    if(tmp == NULL || buffer == NULL)
        printf("malloc error for client conn:%d\n", clientfd);

    if(directory)
    {
        while((dir = readdir(directory)) != NULL)
        {
            if(!strcmp(dir->d_name, ".") || !strcmp(dir->d_name, ".."))
                continue;
            status = stat(dir->d_name, &type);

            if(status == 0)
            {
                filectime = ctime(&type.st_ctime);

                if(dir->d_type != DT_REG)
                    cpylen = snprintf(tmp, BUFSIZE, "dir\t%s\t%s", dir->d_name, filectime);
                else
                    cpylen = snprintf(tmp, BUFSIZE, "file\t%s\t%s", dir->d_name, filectime);

                tmp[cpylen] = 0;

                if((cpylen + msglen) < BUFSIZE)
                {
                    strlcpy(buffer + msglen, tmp, cpylen);
                    msglen += cpylen;
                    no_files += 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    tt_count += msglen;
                    printf("%s", buffer);
                    fflush(stdout);
                    send(clientfd, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0);
                    memset(buffer, 0, BUFSIZE + 5);
                    snprintf(buffer, cpylen, "%s", tmp);
                    msglen = cpylen;
                    cpylen = 0;
                    no_files += 1;
                    no_sends += 1;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                cpylen = snprintf(buffer + msglen, BUFSIZE, "%s%s\n", "file stat error:", dir->d_name);
                msglen += cpylen;
            }
            memset(tmp, 0, BUFSIZE);
        }
    }

    cpylen = strlen(buffer);
    if(msglen == cpylen)
        send(clientfd, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0);

    send(clientfd, ending, strlen(ending), 0);      //sending msg ending for client read to close

    printf("\nlssize :%d\tnofile:%d, msglen:%d\tcpylen:%d\tno_sends:%d\n", tt_count + msglen, no_files, msglen, cpylen, no_sends);

    free(tmp);
    free(buffer);
    closedir(directory);
}
```

Client receiving Code:

```
#define BUFSIZE 1400
while(true)
{
    msgsize = read(socketfd, buffer, BUFSIZE);
    buffer[msgsize] = 0;
    snprintf(ending, 6, "%s", buffer + (strlen(buffer) - 5));

    if(strcmp(ending, "#####") == 0)
    {
        buffer[strlen(buffer) - 5] = 0;

        if(buffer[strlen(buffer) - 1] == '\n')
            printf("%s", buffer);
        else
            printf("%s\n", buffer);
        fflush(stdout);

        break;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%s", buffer);
        memset(buffer, 0, BUFSIZE);
    }
}
```

Server replay debug print:

lssize :19931   nofile:501, msglen:437  cpylen:39   no_sends:**14**

why am I only receiving two packet instead of 14 packets from
server packets of around 1400 bytes each ?

where is the mistake ?

also welcome any code improvement suggestions.

Comment: Do you know about [mcve] ? The ideal question is where readers can copy/paste code into their environment and get the same errors you are getting.  I think you're missing a few things in that regard. The simplest `CC` or `make` cmd would also be useful. As a comment on your code, I would have expected a loop in your server code. I also think I see variables used that aren't declared. Sorry I don't have any recent experience with sockets etc, so that's all I can add to your issue. Good luck!

Comment: You'll also get many more readers if you add a [c] tag to your code. Veteran readers here on S.O. read only questions tagged with their areas of interest. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks shellter, I'm updating accordingly

Comment: Dont use `<br>` to get line breaks. Use 4 spaces at the front of each line, or you can use the `{}` tool from the Edit menu on mouse-selected text to format as `code/data/requiredOutput/ExactErrMsgs`. Good luck.

Comment: And you say *only receiving one packet*. is that of size 437 or 39 or ?? I don't see any place in your code that would be generating that `lssize ...` msg. Good luck.

Comment: You MUST correctly and completely handle the results returned by system calls like send/recv

Comment: Client - asking to recv [ BUFSIZE + 5 ] bytes sounds dubious - how big is the buffer?  Must be at least [BUFSIZE + 6] to prevent OOB writes.

Comment: @MartinJames client recv buffer is of BUFSIZE + 5 ~ 1405, client will always receive 1400 bytes only from server. the extra 5 bytes in client is for for checking ending of message.

By the way I have also tested for making both server and client buffers to Same as BUFSIZE. I see still sever is not sending total numbers 14 buffers.

Comment: @Sekhar ' client will always receive 1400 bytes only from server' well, if you are using TCP byte streams, , you cannot say that.

Comment: 'tmp[cpylen] = 0;' seems pointless because the strlcpy does not copy it, and is a potential, (though unlikely), OOB write.

Comment: There are too many bugs.  You need to test and debug this code after fixing the missing return values handling etc.

Comment: @MartinJames, could you please elaborate, what do you mean by  'If your using TCP bytes streams, you can't say that '  ?

Comment: Thank you @MartinJames can you aslo suggest how to debug, because I have tried debugging using wireshark also, client only receiving last 2 packets out of 14 packets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to the bugs pointed out in the comments, there are more fundamental issues with your code that are too extensive to merely comment on.

This code implies multithreaded use:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
chdir(pclient->pwd);
directory = opendir(".");
pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
```

**BUT**, this code assumes the current working directory is always the current function's `pclient->pwd`:

```
 status = stat(dir->d_name, &type);
```

It won't be if another thread calls `chdir()` to another directory while the loop is running, so your results

`stat()` **always** checks a relative path from the current working directory **of the entire process**.  Which, in your posted code, can change.

A good rule to follow is to **NEVER** do things that change any global property of a process if you're writing multithreaded code.

Your use of `snprintf()` is also bug-prone.  For example:

```
cpylen = snprintf(buffer + msglen, BUFSIZE, "%s%s\n", "file stat error:", dir->d_name);
```

Per [**7.21.6.5 The snprintf function**, paragraph 2 of the C11 standard](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.5p3)(bolding mine):

> The snprintf function **returns the number of characters that would have been written had n been sufficiently large**, not counting the terminating null character, or a negative value if an encoding error occurred. Thus, **the null-terminated output has been completely written if and only if the returned value is nonnegative and less than n**.

You are blindly assuming that every one of your calls to `snprintf()` work.  If any one call to `snprintf()` fails, your message contents are wildly indeterminate and your value for `msglen` will not accurately reflect the contents of your buffer.

That means this code won't send anything:

```
cpylen = strlen(buffer);
if(msglen == cpylen)
    send(clientfd, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Andrew, I agree your point about chdir and multi threading, pclient is a struct queue node which is different for each thread pool thread I have created.